# MultiTrigger: Combined DataTrigger and PropertyTrigger not working

Tags: wpf, image, datatrigger, multidatatrigger, multitrigger

I have a problem where I need to combine a `DataTrigger` and a `PropertyTrigger` into a `MultiDataTrigger` to show an `Image` in a `GridViewColumn` (combined with a `TreeView`, it's a custom control I'm using). I experimented and searched some thins on the internet and this is how far I've come:

```
 <Image Width="16" 
        Height="16" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill">
           <Image.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                  <Setter Property="Source" 
                          Value="{Binding ScorecardNiveau, Converter={StaticResource ScorecardNiveauToImageConverter}}" />
                     <Style.Triggers>
                       <MultiDataTrigger>
                          <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                             <Condition Binding="{Binding WpfSettings.IsExpanded}" Value="True" />
                             <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source}" Value="/folder_closed.png" />
                          </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                          <Setter Property="Source" Value="/folder_open.png" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
            </Image.Style>
  </Image>
```

Now, initially, the `Image` can have two images, according to the `Converter`. Either the folder_open, or another one (not important now). Now what I want is: when the TreeViewNode is expanded (`WpfSetting.IsExpanded = true`) and when the Image Source is folder_closed, I want the Image to get the folder_open image. I think I am close with the above code, but it's not really working. The `Image` isn't changing at all when I open a `TreeViewNode`.

I think I am doing something wrong with the Condition on the `RelativeSource=Self`, but I am not sure.

Anyone who can help me please? Thanks in advance.

Of course, more information/code can be provided if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with RelativeSource=Self but when you try to compare Source(which is of type ImageSource) to string value ("/folder_closed.png"), it return false

Try the following Condition :

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding ScorecardNiveau, Converter={StaticResource ScorecardNiveauToImageConverter}}" Value="/folder_closed.png" />
```

Comment: I tried it and it's still not working, although it makes a lot of sense comparing the return value of the converter.

Comment: I think the problem is with the WpfSettings.IsExpanded property. When I debug it with a MultiValueConverter, the IsExpanded property has "UnsetDependencyProperty" as value, maybe the same when the trigger is called.

Comment: Yes could be. I tried a similar test code with IsExpanded as true/false and it worked as expected

Comment: Okay, then I will need to find another solution. Thank you! Will mark as answered because the solution given should answer the question :)